# Ubuntu 16 is unable to detect second monitor and unable to make internet conection after restart

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, internet, display-resolution, vga

All was woking fine until today, when I made a simple restart. After that, the system is unable to detect a second display. If I start my laptop with the VGA plug-in , the resolution of the built-in display is fine but if I start without it, the resolution is very low and I not able to change it, even if I plug the cord. In adition, the brightness control doesn't work. So I went to /sys/class/backlight and surprisingly it was empty. Few weeks ago I change the grub file the part "...acpi_backlight=native" because this allowed me use control keys to change the brightness and I remember that the backlight folder had two subfolders: one related to intel and the another one to nvidia.

To try to solve the problem I changed to vendor but the backlight folder still empty. Then, I changed to video and now I have an acpi_video0 folder, but it doesn't make a difference in the system.

The problem gets even worst because I was unable o make an internet conection either wireless or by wire. So I can not install anything easly and I have to write this in my phone. This issue is really extrange as it seems that the system doesn't detect the ethernet cable or the WiFi antena. I said that because the icon of the top right corner (that with a baseball stadium shape) indicate "no network devices available" and the cable is already conected.

I will apreciate any help that this community could provide me.

Comment: does it help to boot an old kernel ?

Comment: Oh, that solves the issue! Now I'm writing this from my computer.  I'm wondering why if the new version was installed 6 days ago, the issue pop up until now. That the kernel updates take effect until manual restart?

Comment: yes you have to reboot to enable or use a new kernel. Use the old kernel and/or file a bug report against the new.